# How to write Do Until Cell value = 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I mainly build most of my macros from already written codes from different people.
But I haven't found one that does this.

I need the macro to keep repeating a certain task until the cell of the value = 0
The 0 comes from a COUNTIF formula.

1. So I have a text ID in cell A2,
2. it will offset to cell B2, enter a formula (which is a COUNTIF formula)
3. Then it will offset to cell C2, enter a formula (which gives me another Text ID)
4. Then it will copy C2 to A3, and then repeats step 2
5. My goal is to keep doing this until the COUNTIF value in Column B = 0

My current macro is

```
Sub macro ()
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(TASKPRED!C1,RC1,TASKPRED!C10,""Y"")"
    
'Add formula #2 (Type the "Driving successor")
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=INDEX(TASKPRED!C[-1],MATCH(RC1&""Y"",TASKPRED!C1&TASKPRED!C10,0),0)"
'Copy to new line
Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
 i = 2
 Do Until Range(i, 2).Value = 0
[MACRO ABOVE HERE]
 i = i + 1
 Loop
```

Thanks

Comment: `Cells(i, 2).value` Ranges need to be `Range("B" & i)`

Comment: @Warcupine: Why do you think so? Both terms are equivalent

Comment: @FunThomas wouldn't the range need to be `Range(cells(i, 2), cells(i, 2)).value`? If i try `Range(i, 2).value` I get runtime error 1004 - application or object defined error.

Comment: `.cells(row, col)` *is* a Range. And, if you prefer, you can use also the column letter: `Cells(i, "B")` is valid

Comment: @FunThomas I'm aware but if you use `Range()` it needs to be either `cells(), cells()` or `ColRow` format they have `Range(i, 2)` that will error.

Comment: My first question looking at this is whether it works as you'd expect if you just run the first Macro lots of times in succession. And if so are you doing anything manually between each execution (such as changing what cells are selected).

Comment: @Warcupine: Misundertood your first comment, sorry. Statement should be `Do Until Cells(i, 2).Value = 0` or `Do Until Range("B" & i).Value = 0`

Comment: Also, "it didn't work" is not the most helpful. Do you get an error message? If so what? Or are the results just not what you're expecting?

Comment: @SteveLovell 
Q- My first question looking at this is whether it works as you'd expect if you just run the first Macro lots of times in succession.
A- yes manually it works fine, if I let it loop it will never end so I'm trying to write a "Do until value = 0 loop"

Comment: Thanks @Warcupine, but when I changed it to Range("B" & i), it skipped the entire loop

Answer (score 0):

### Calling a Sub in Do...Loop

- If the formulas are correct, this should do.
- This doesn't feel right, there should be a better way.
- Not tested.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub pasteFormulas(cel As Range)
    cel.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 _
        = "=COUNTIFS(TASKPRED!C1,RC1,TASKPRED!C10,""Y"")"
    cel.Offset(, 2).Formula2R1C1 _
        = "=INDEX(TASKPRED!C[-1],MATCH(RC1&""Y"",TASKPRED!C1&TASKPRED!C10,0),0)"
    cel.Offset(1).Value = cel.Offset(, 2).Value
End Sub

Sub doPasteFormulas()
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Do
        i = i + 1
        pasteFormulas Cells(i, 1)
        cValue = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Loop Until cValue = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's giving me an error because "pasteFormulas" is not declared yet

Comment: Not sure what that means. What are the exact error number and the description, and in which line of which procedure does it occur?

Comment: oh sorry, I tried it again and it worked fine, even though it continued for a few more cells after cellvalue=0 which produced "#N/A" values.

The bigger problem is that I couldn't integrate this macro into the end of my main long macro because of the couple "Sub" and "End Sub" in there, when I tried to remove those "Sub" and "End Sub" the macro stopped and didn't reach your bit